# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined after country drop down selection

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to select state from a drop down, after selecting the country and I am to select the state, I do get this error even though everything looks perfect to me

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at FormComponent.getStateOnCountrySelection
```

Here is the ts file:

```
getStateOnCountrySelection(id){
    this.selectedStatesOption = [];
    this.countriesService.getStates(id).subscribe((data:any) =>{
      this.selectedStatesOption.push(data);
    });
  }
```

Here is the service class class to pick the states

```
public getStates(id: number): Observable<State[]> {
    let selectedStates;
    this.getCountries().subscribe((data:any) =>{
      let states = data["states"];
      selectedStates = states.filter((data:any) =>{
        return parseInt(data.id) == id
      });
    });
    return selectedStates;
  }
```

Please what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here

1. You aren't returning anything from the function in the service.
2. The data is obtained asynchronously. It cannot be returned synchronously like you're attempting to. You need to return the observable from the function instead. You could use RxJS `map` operator to filter the response as per the requirement.

Service

```js
public getStates(id: number): Observable<State[]> {
  let selectedStates;
  return this.getCountries().pipe(
    map((data: any[]) => (data['states'].filter(state => parseInt(state.id) == id)) as State[])
  );
}
```

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921) in it's entirety to know how async data works.

Comment: after selecting country, the state drop down is empty

Comment: and on console it returns just one state

Comment: Check if the response `data` actually does contain all the states.

Comment: Then you'd need to check if the backend service returns correct data.

Answer (score 0):

You are retuning an array not an observable.

This is an approximate function. Maybe have issues.

```
public getStates(id: number): Observable<State[]> {

    return this.getCountries().pipe(map((data:any) =>{
      
      let states = data["states"];
      return  states.filter((data:any) =>{
        return parseInt(data.id) == id
      });
    }));
  }
```

Comment: returns just one state and state is not populated

Comment: use a console.log before the filter and check if data is comming populated from the server.